# Can't send push notification to single iOS user on Azure Mobile Services in ionic

Tags: ios, azure, ionic-framework, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I know this is a somehow duplicate question of this [ANH push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174607/cant-send-push-notification-to-single-ios-user-on-azure-mobile-services)  just some other stuff with me is that I want to send a notification to a specific user for that I registered user with a unique tag

`if (this.globalService.isIos) {
        // Register for notifications.
        console.log('ios reg');
        this.client.push.register('apns', handle, {
          mytemplate: { body: { aps: { alert: "{$(message_nlNL)}" }},
tags: [uniqueTag]}
        });
    }`

and it is registering successfully but when I send notification from ANH with tag expression I don't receive any push notification but without tag, it is working and I am able to receive a notification on my iPhone.

I want to send a notification to a specific user that is why the tag is there but not working in my case. Any help would be appreciated.